# 2 WD hardrives won't fit in Thermaltake

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I recently bought the blacxduet thermaltake and got files i thought were lost from 3 old hard drives.I then went to pop my WD 1 TB hard drives  and my WD 1.5TB hard rive in but they won't fit, 
I'd would be so grateful for any help resolving this.
Thanks!

Here is a link to pics of a hard drive that i already recovered data using the thermaltake and then the two WD drives I can't get to fit

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvlto.jpg

Comment: How exactly aren't they fitting?

Comment: the others slid right in, these seem to be catching

Comment: photos of the drives that fit and those that don't?

Comment: im not sure how to post photos, have to look it up,i did take photos with my iphone

Comment: whats the easiest way to show you guys the pictures

Comment: Upload them to imgur then [edit] the question to include the links. You don't have yet enough rep to embed the pictures, hence the suggestion to post as links, but anyone else can edit that for you.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/O3qYN

Comment: Umm... The top 2 drives are NOT bare SATA drives, or not "standard", and won't fit in ANY standard dock, they have the USB interface built in and it is a USB 3.0 Micro-B plug, you just need the correct cable. If they don't work that way then you probably will never retrieve the data off of the drive because the interface is built into the control circuitry of the drive's interface card. These are taken out of external enclosures and will not function in a SATA-USB dock. You may actually be damaging them by trying to insert them. The bottom pic is a standard SATA drive.

Comment: oh, i didn't jam them in, they didn't easily go so i stopped.I don't know a lot about this stuff,I appreciate you letting me know

Comment: Just get a USB 3.0 Micro-B cable and connect it to a USB 3.0 port on the computer (2.0 likely doesn't supply enough power). If you can access the drive, it's a win for you... If not, might as well just throw it out as the USB interface and the control circuitry are all in one on those drives, if it has failed the drive is garbage.

Comment: Can you take a picture from the underside of the disk shown in the first picture ?  I posit that what you have is a regular SATA disk (which will fit in a system) with an "interposer" to convert it to a USB3 disk.  If this is the case, you can remove the USB3 interposer board and you should be able to plug it in. What is the exact model of the drive ?

Comment: WD10JMVW-11AJGS1

Comment: If  a HD clicks when plugged into computer , is all hope lost for that HD?

Answer (score 1):

The first two drives in your photo gallery appear to be unusual *USB-only* WD hard disks. These drives were never intended to be removed from the enclosure they came in, and cannot be used in another enclosure.

If the drives still work -- judging by the way the pins are bent, they may have seen some abuse -- you can recover files from them by plugging a USB cable into the socket on the back.

Comment: (You can attempt to recover) bent pins make that a little less likely